# What is the reason for calling "linear transformation"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, linear-transformations

Why we call a "vector space homomorphism" as a "linear transformation" ?

I guess that because it transforms a homogeneous linear polynomial in to a homogeneous linear polynomial. Is it correct ? or is there any other reason for this ?

Comment: a homogeneous polynomial is a polynomial whose non zero terms all have the same degree

Comment: I would bet that "linear transformation" was terminology used before "homomorphism." (Edit: [indeed](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html), by nearly 100 years).

Comment: Looking at [earliest known uses of the term *linear*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/l.html), it seems *linear equation* was used in 1816, *linear operator* in 1837, and *linear function* and *linear transformation* in 1843. So I would guess linear transformations were originally called such because they appear in linear equations.

Comment: A really use full information. Thank you Rahul.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's literally "linear". In any vector space a line is for the form $tx+y$, with $t\in\mathbb F$ and $x,y$ two fixed points. If you apply a linear transformation $T$ to the points in the line, you get points of the form 
$$
T(tx+y)=t\,Tx+Ty,
$$
another line. So $T$ takes lines to lines: "linear".

Comment: So does translation, though, and that's not a linear map

Comment: If this is wrong, feel free to explain why the word "linear" is used.